# if not found any page or url then redirect index.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect like `http://localhost/project/g47sh` to `http://localhost/project/index.php`

But when I am write on URL `http://localhost/project/g47sh` then 404 error is generated so I want to if any page or directory not found the redirect index.php and also pass not found URL path.

Comment: Depending on http server you used. Can you tell me that what http server you are using? e.g. Apache, IIS etc. And also OS of the server.

Comment: Can you show the rule you've tried?